# How to generate Codenarc report for Main and Test classes using different rule-sets?

Tags: gradle, codenarc

I am using CodeNarc for coding best practices in my project and it's working absolutely fine. In general Codenarc makes the report separately for all the Main classes and Test classes based on the rulesets defined in the config file(in my case codenarc.xml). I have used to following code snippet in my project:

```
apply plugin: 'codenarc'

dependencies {
    codenarc group: 'org.codenarc', name: 'CodeNarc', version: '0.17'
}

codenarc {
    configFile = file('src/conf/codenarc.xml')
}
```

I don't want to enforce all the rules for both Main and Test classes (**e.g. I may want to exclude some rule-sets from Test classes**). Is there any way doing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can configure the `CodeNarc` tasks individually:

```
codenarcMain {
    configFile = ...
}

codenarcTest {
    configFile = ...
}
```

PS: I recommend to use shorthand dependency notation:

```
dependencies {
    codenarc "org.codenarc:CodeNarc:0.17"
}
```